# Jquery getscript on fail never fire the event

Tags: jquery, getscript

I m trying to fire a pixel inside script but the URL is either 404 or failed. My problem is that i m trying to catch the error with get script but it doesnt fall inside.
Here is my code

```
$.getScript( URL )
.done(function( script, textStatus ) {
   alert(1);
})
.fail(function( jqxhr, settings, exception ) {
                alert(1);
        });
```

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: GET https://zipi/binary/test/pixel.jsp?script_reg_0=7322_1=_2=101390_3=GB_4=82.166.140.125_5={5}_6={6}_7={7}&_=1414478324465 net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED jquery.min.js:18
GET https://zipi/binary/test/pixel.jsp?script_reg_0=7322_1=_2=101390_3=GB_4=82.166.140.125_5={5}_6={6}_7={7}&_=1414478329101 net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED jquery.min.js:18
GET https://zipi/binary/test/pixel-script.jsp?reg_script&_=1414478331684 net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED jquery.min.js:18
GET https://zipi/binary/test/pixel.jsp?script_fatsregistration_no_parames&_=1414478332368 net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED